# Trying to build a more intelligent RegEx Word Counter in JQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, word-count

I'm trying to write a regex word count, but most of the examples I've found only cover a portion of the following situations:

1. hello,there = should be 2 words (note there is no space after the
   comma)
2. hello , there = should be 2 words (note the space before and
   after the comma)
3. $10,000 = should be 1 word
4. hello there ? = should be 2 words (note the space before the
   question mark)
5. hello-there = should be 2 words
6. http://www.google.com = should be 1 word
7. http://www.google.com/analytics = should be 1 word

I'm currently using the following code in jquery

```
var total_words = $.trim($("#mytextbox").value).split(/[\s\-\.\\\/\?\!]+/).length
```

but it only covers situations #3 and #5.

Covering URLs is less of a priority to me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need a natural language parser (NLP), not a regex. See http://devdirective.com/post/131/extracting-text-natural-language-processing-versus-regular-expressions

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I agree that that would be the fastest (computing wise) method however coding a NLP for word count when RegEx can do it is just...well too much work unless this is a heavy consumed page or service.

Comment: @abc123 - I didn't mean that an NLP would be faster (it probably would not be). I mean that counting "words" in a natural language is beyond the capabilities of even the most powerful regex engines. It is safe to assume that the OP's "following situations" are not exhaustive. For example, "google.com" should probably be counted as one word, but "I have a cat.I also have a dog." should be counted as 9 words (rather than 8). "hello-there" should, apparently, be counted as 2 words, but "pre-emptive" is clearly 1 word. Regex is simply not designed to handle these kinds of problems.

Comment: I'd add that even defining a "word" can be tricky. Some might argue that "[office-mate](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/52269/22189)" is one word while others would argue for two. How "many" words there are depends on what you are trying to accomplish. And if you don't care that much about accuracy, then why bother with complicated word-counting rules in the first place? (Don't even get started with [contractions](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/80635/22189).)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following RegEx will work for all your examples:

```
var total_words = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@‌​#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|(&)|('\w+)|(\w+'‌​\w+)|(\w+')|(\w+)/gi
```

This RegEx was converted from JSoft to JavaScript:

```
(\b((?#protocol)https?|ftp)://((?#domain)[-A-Z0-9.]+)((?#file)/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?((?#parameters)\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|\w+
```

This first section defines any url type item:

```
(\b((?#protocol)https?|ftp)://((?#domain)[-A-Z0-9.]+)((?#file)/[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?((?#parameters)\?[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)
```

The section section is for currency with or without decimals:

```
[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?
```

Finally the third section matches words:

```
\w+
```

Comment: Using it as 
`var total_words = $.trim($("#mytextbox").value).match(/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|\w+/i).length;`
seems to always return a null value, no matter what I type.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out. I changed the regex to 

`/(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|\w+/gi`

and that seems to have done the trick!

Comment: not a problem, updated answer to your regex mentioned.  I just did a conversion to JavaScript RegEx, unfortunately i didn't test it.

Comment: updated the regex to 

`var total_words = /(\b(https?|ftp):\/\/([\-A-Z0-9.]+)(\/[\-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?(\?[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|!:,.;]*)?)|[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?|(&)|('\w+)|(\w+'\w+)|(\w+')|(\w+)/gi`

that will count words with apostrophes (e.g. it's, they're, 'quote') as a single word and will count ampersands as a word (e.g. you & me = 3 words).

Comment: updated answer again to make sure people don't get confused, good updates.

Answer (score 0):

Since javascripts regex engine evaluate's from left-to-right you can specify more specific regex and then more general regex at the end

```
\b(https?://\S+|\d+(,\d+)+|\w+)\b 
   ------------  --------- ---
         |           |      |->general
         |           |->less specific
         |->more specific regex
```

Comment: Counts `1,000,000` as two words, `http://fail.com/?major=fail` would be tree words.

Comment: Thanks. However, using a split on this expression seems to only cover situations 3, 6, and 7.